# How to compute the magnetic force between two electromagnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, dipole-moment

I wanna compute the magnetic forces between two solenoids with iron cores, is there any analytic formula for this?

I guess that dipole-dipole interaction in the link "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Magnetic_dipole-dipole_interaction" can be used, it says
$$
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{m}_1,\mathbf{m}_2)=\frac{3\mu_0}{4\pi r^5}\left[(\mathbf{m}_1\cdot \mathbf{r})\mathbf{m}_2+(\mathbf{m}_2\cdot \mathbf{r})\mathbf{m}_1+(\mathbf{m}_1\cdot \mathbf{m}_2)\mathbf{r}-\frac{5(\mathbf{m}_1\cdot \mathbf{r})(\mathbf{m}_2\cdot \mathbf{r})}{r^2}\mathbf{r}\right]
$$
but I don't know how to compute the dipole moment $\mathbf{m}$ for solenoid with iron core.

From the link "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Magnetic_moment_of_a_solenoid", it seems a solenoid has moment $NIS$, but how about adding an iron core inside it?

Comment: There are, in general, no such analytical formulas. If you have a technical need to compute these things, the best way is to use magnetostatics software that does the necessary numerics. Probably the most simple tool I am aware of is FEMM (http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage). The author has also included a list of links to other tools of this kind. FEMM only works for 2.5d problems, i.e. your magnets need to be either planar or have axial-symmetry, but there are tools that can do real 3d.

Comment: Thanks, CuriousOne. But how about the analytic formula I listed above? It computes the force by using dipole moment. It seems if I have a moment computation formula for solenoid with icon core, then it is solved?

Comment: You will get an approximation that works well in the far field (distance between magnets is, at least, several times their size), which is usually not where electromagnets are technically useful/being used. In the near field (distance between magnets is smaller than their size) you will have to deal with the non-linear magnetic properties of the materials, and that's best done by numerical methods.

Comment: I see, so FEM is unavoidable for near field problem. Actually, I hope I can use the far field formulation for my problem, and in that case my optimization can be much more simpler.

Comment: For the near field, yes. If you are lucky enough to be able to work in the far field, then the dipole formula should work well enough. As for the iron, I would look up the magnetization curve for whatever material you are planning to use. That will give you a rough $\mu_r$ for the increase in magnetic field due to the material. Since you can adjust the currents and the number of turns on the windings, that should be enough degrees of freedom to fine-tune your final design.

Comment: Many thanks CuriousOne, so that means the above force equation is scaled by the $\mu_r$ of the material, right?

Comment: Yes. If you can neglect the change in magnetization of your materials, then the dipole interaction should work just fine. Just curious... what's the application? I am not going to be offended if you don't want to answer that. :-)

Comment: It's not quite clear yet : )  but basically I wanna construct a tiny network of the magnets and control the forces therein.

Comment: I see... that's an interesting idea...I can see that system doing some very interesting things. If I may make a suggestion... put two coils orthogonally in there at every node of your network, that way you can control the angular orientation completely. Good luck!

Comment: Indeed, orientation can be quite important, thanks for the inspiring suggestion!